# Sending message to a spesific channel with the channel name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was trying to send messages to a spesific channel name, but it did not work. Is that possible in discord.py or should I use channel ID

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
      if message.channel.id=="123456789":  
      news=client.get_channel("general")
      news.send("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

The discord.py documentation has this to say:

> **get_channel(id)**
>
> Returns a channel with the given ID.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> id (int) – The ID to search for.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The returned channel or None if not found.

So yes, you need the ID.

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem, and I find out that you can make it with the channel name

Comment: if you solved your problem, submit it as an answer and mark that as correct